# Inserting PHP array into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, ajax

I have a html table that is converted to JSON and sent over via AJAX to PHP.
I've decoded the JSON object and now have a PHP array.
I'd like to insert this array or rather the contents of it into a MySQL database.

I'm confused on some of the methodologies out there.
what is the ideal method to prevent SQL injection?
I see a number of methods that look like so;

```
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
    {
        $price = $array["price"][$key];
        ...................................
    }
```

this doesn't seem to work, or at least I can't get php to print or echo out what $price is.

I've tried this:

```
     foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
         {
           $price = $value["price"];
          ...................................
         }
```

This i can get echo or print_r to display the value.

First question is: what is the purpose of $key here in terms of inserting these values into MySQ?
Second is: why doesn't the first one return the expected result, like that of the second code snippet? echo should display the value of $price?
Lastly, from this assuming both methods are valid, an insert statement like below is correct for actually pushing the data into MySQL?

```
       $sql = mysql_query("insert into Daily_Requests values ('','$price','$item','$etc...','$etc....')");
```

Regards

**EDIT**

Here is my JSON:

```
[{"Price":"5000","Manufacturer":"Newton","Model":"84x26x10 43u","Model_info":"Newton 84x26x10 43u","Type":"Rack","Height_in":"83.97637795","Height_mm":"2133","Width_in":"25.98425197","Width_mm":"660","Description":"Newton 84x26x10 43u","Depth_in":"10","Depth_mm":"254","Mount_Type":"Floor Mount","Rack_UNITS":"43","Rack_INSIDE_HEIGHT_mm":"1911","Rack_INSIDE_WIDTH_mm":"584","Rack_INSIDE_DEPTH_mm":"","ASSET_TYPE":"Rack","Phases":"","Status":"","Date":"2017-01-11","Submitted":"","Image File / Web Info":"","Site":"Orlando"}]
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Hint: The right way to do this is to use prepared statements with placeholder values.

Comment: please add the structure of JSON you are getting in question. It'll become more clear then.

Comment: *what is the purpose of $key here in terms of inserting these values into MySQ?* --> it just array's key, try to `print_r($array)` first and take a look on you array. basically i'm saying `$price = $value["price"]` is like accessing `$value[$key]["price"]` in `for($key = 0; $key < count($array); $key++){..}` -- if the key is indeed an integer.

Comment: The procedure will depend on the JSON structure. Please provide an example of the JSON data.

Comment: @tadman thank you, I'll update to one of the newer functions.

Comment: @Gabriel  JSON posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you enter the loop

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    #loop entered here after open

    #each value of the array is accessible

    #end loop here before close
     }
```

With `$key` being the index value of the array as an integer and  `$value` as the actual variable holding the value at that index.  `$array` inside the loop is the same as outside loop.  `$value` represents the slice of that array.

once you load the data into a new variable as `$price = $value["price"]` it is available until the close of the loop and resets to the new value when looped over again.

So your SQL statement out of the loop will contain the last values held by 
$array.

Comment: This makes sense, I think.  $key is just the 'dynamic index' of that currently accessed slice of the array? While $value is the literal value of that specific $key. Once the loop closes that $key changes and thus the $value.  So when I attempted to echo $price, I'm not accessing the value but rather that slice of the array? `$price = $array["price"][$key];`therefore I should access it as you did via:`$price = $value["price"]`?

Comment: by stating `$price = $value["price"]`  you have loaded `$price`with the value held by `$value["price"]`.  So just echoing `$price` will be the same is echoing `$value["price"]`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have doubts about how to access or loop throuhg the elements of an array, use `var_dump` to visualize its structure.

I see you have an array of objects and I understand that each object is a row. So:

```
foreach($array as $object) {
    //Here you have each object in $object
    //$object is {"Price":"5000","Manufacturer":"Newton",...}

    //Lets build the query to insert this row. I'm gonna do this with a query string as you're already using mysql_query, but as suggested you should migrate to PDO.

    $query='';

    foreach($object as $key=>$value) {
        //To answer your $key question, here $key are Price, Manufacturer, Model, etc and $value are the correspondig values for each key

        if($query) $query.=','; //add the comma if it's not the fist var
        $query.='`'.mysql_real_escape_string($key).'`=\' '.mysql_real_escape_string($value).'\'';
    }

    $query='insert into Daily_Requests set '.$query;

    mysql_query($query);
}
```